Issue with createToken Method in AppController Class: Cannot read properties of undefined ('reading createToken') in nodeJs
CHALLENGE:
I created a class called AppController and added some methods to it (see code below). I observed that a particular method "createToken", throws an error anytime I call the login method (a method that uses the createToken method) in the class. This error only shows up when I create the createToken method normally and call it with this.createToken.
class AppController {

  /**
   * Generate token for user. Expiration 5hrs
   * @param {User} user - User object to generate token for
   */
  createToken(user) {
    return sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email, status: user.status }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '5h' });
  };

  /**
   * Login user
   * @param {Object} req - Express Request
   * @param {Object} res - Express Response
   * @return Payload on Success
   */
  async login(req, res) {
    try {
      const { value, error } = requestValidator.Login.validate(req.body);

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      // validate email/username
      const username = User.findOne({ username: value.email_or_username });
      const email = User.findOne({ email: value.email_or_username });
    
      const user = await Promise.any([username, email]);
      if (!user) {
        return handleResponse(res, 400, "email, username or password incorrect");
      }
    
      if (userStatus.deactivated == user.status) {
        const resolve = "Account deactivated - resolve with: /api/v1/general/forget-password";
        return handleResponse(res, 400, resolve);
      }

      // validate password
      const matched = await compare(value.password, user.password);

      if (!matched) {
        return handleResponse(res, 400, "email, username or password incorrect");
      }

      const token = this.createToken(user); // where the error comes from
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({
          message: 'Authentication successful',
          token
        });
  
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof MongooseError) {
        return handleResponse(res, 500, "We have a mongoose problem", error);
      }
      if (error instanceof Joi.ValidationError) {
        return handleResponse(res, 400, error.details[0].message);
      }
      if (error instanceof JsonWebTokenError) {
        return handleResponse(res, 500, error.message, error);
      }
      return handleResponse(res, 500, error.message, error)
    }
  };
}

ATTEMPT: But if I make ita static method and call it with the class I don't get any error and it works successfully.
class AppController {

  /**
   * Generate token for user. Expiration 5hrs
   * @param {User} user - User object to generate token for
   */
  static createToken(user) {
    return sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email, status: user.status }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '5h' });
  };

  /**
   * Login user
   * @param {Object} req - Express Request
   * @param {Object} res - Express Response
   * @return Payload on Success
   */
  async login(req, res) {
    try {
      const { value, error } = requestValidator.Login.validate(req.body);

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      // validate email/username
      const username = User.findOne({ username: value.email_or_username });
      const email = User.findOne({ email: value.email_or_username });
    
      const user = await Promise.any([username, email]);
      if (!user) {
        return handleResponse(res, 400, "email, username or password incorrect");
      }
    
      if (userStatus.deactivated == user.status) {
        const resolve = "Account deactivated - resolve with: /api/v1/general/forget-password";
        return handleResponse(res, 400, resolve);
      }

      // validate password
      const matched = await compare(value.password, user.password);

      if (!matched) {
        return handleResponse(res, 400, "email, username or password incorrect");
      }

      const token = AppController.createToken(user); // No error
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({
          message: 'Authentication successful',
          token
        });
  
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof MongooseError) {
        return handleResponse(res, 500, "We have a mongoose problem", error);
      }
      if (error instanceof Joi.ValidationError) {
        return handleResponse(res, 400, error.details[0].message);
      }
      if (error instanceof JsonWebTokenError) {
        return handleResponse(res, 500, error.message, error);
      }
      return handleResponse(res, 500, error.message, error)
    }
  };
}

QUESTION: I know I found a way around it but I love to know why this occurred and get a good understanding of what was going on (why this.createToken didn't work) because I've created a lot of classes and methods and haven't experienced such challenge before.

How are you calling login()? At a guess, I'd say you've detached the login method from its instance

This question is similar to: How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

TL;DR if you have app.post('/login', controller.login) that won't work. You'd need app.post('/login, controller.login.bind(controller)) or app.post('/login', (req, res) => controller.login(req, res))
